# File comparing APIs/Code

Tags: java, api, file, compare

I have to program a file comparing - only (plain) text files and pdf files - algorithm. I allowed to use APIs or other codes.

What i have found:

- Google match-diff libs
- Windows file compare command
- Linux diff command
- Many libs that are based on google api or diff from linux

So they compare two files line by line but if i have for example this:

```
package pack1;

some imports

/**
 *
 * @author author1
 */
public class Class1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("ABaBAb " + count("ABaBAb") + "\n");
        System.out.print("ABCabC " + count("ABCabC") + "\n");
        System.out.print("ABaBAb " + count("ABaBAb") + "\n");
        System.out.print("ABCDabdf " + count("ABCDabdf") + "\n");
        System.out.print("ABCab " + count("ABCab") + "\n");
    }
    static HashMap<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public static int count(String s) {
        does something
    }
}
```

and this:

```
package pack2;

some imports

/**
 *
 * @author changed
 */
public class Class2 {
static HashMap<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public static int count(String s) {
        does something
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("asdff " + countDifferentChars("asdff") + "\n");
        System.out.print("Afda " + countDifferentChars("Afda") + "\n");
        System.out.print("ABab " + countDifferentChars("ABab") + "\n");
        System.out.print("sadr " + countDifferentChars("sadr") + "\n");
        System.out.print("Afasd " + countDifferentChars("Afasd") + "\n");
    }

}
```

they do not really know the differences because they, as I said, compare line by line. I am looking for something that should know that package, the System.out.print and other things are nearly the same. It also should be able to tell that the count methods are the same (they only were moved).

Are there any APIs that are able to do this? Please do let me know if you have more questions.

Thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an AI task (understanding types of statements etc.). I am making something like this, but it isn't ready yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the overall purpose is. What will be done with these comparison results?

Comment: So i should compare documents, often java homeworks, and say if they are the same, nearly the same, ... ,not the same. It would be also very good if I show a percentage. I do not have to code it myself. I am allowed to use APIs or other codes but they nearly all compare line by line

Comment: Oh, school assignments... usually nobody knows what they're good for. Anyway, it's a really complicated thing asked of you. Not sure what the prof thought there